# Writing out multiple lists to a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to write out multiple lists to a file at once, specifically trying to get each list to write out one value each per line and then have a new line at the end. I tried to implement it as:

```
for p in ID:
        o.write(ID[p], Name[p], HP[p], ATK[p], DEF[p], SPA[p], SPD[p], SPE[p])
```

But write() only takes one argument, so naturally the above code fails. 
It's important to me that each line that gets written to the output file has one value from each list, separated by a comma, and a newline when each of the 8 lists finishes once.

Comment: Have you tried turning that all into one large string before giving it to `write`?

Comment: How about using `o.writelines`? then write a newline between each.

Comment: ...or use json.dump on a list of lists. Then load your data via json.load later.

Comment: how about [mre] - so we can see what you really do? it is absolutely unclear what all those variables are

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood correctly, but try doing this:

```
for p in range(len(ID)):
    o.write(f'{ID[p]}, {Name[p]}, {HP[p]}, {ATK[p]}, {DEF[p]}, {SPA[p]}, {SPD[p]}, {SPE[p]}\n')
```

Comment: OP is writing in the order of the indexes in the ID list. `range(len(ID))` is a different ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a CSV file.

```
import csv

with open('output.txt', 'w', newline='') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows([ID[p], Name[p], HP[p], ATK[p], DEF[p],
        SPA[p], SPD[p], SPE[p]] for p in ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
list1 = ['Abdulvahab','Kharadi','39']
list2 = ['Sam', 'James', '30']
list3 = ['Mike', 'Panjeri', '43']

lists = (list1, list2, list3)
for list in lists:
    row = ','.join(list) 
    row += '\n'
    with open('staff.txt','a') as f:
        f.write(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use zip to combine the lists and join to combine he string representations of the values for each list:

```
for values in zip(ID,Name,HP,ATK,DEF,SPA,SPD,SPE):
    o.write(",".join(map(str,values))+"\n")
```

Comment: The way the question is presented, OP wants things written in the order of the index in the ID list. Here you write from top of lists down.

Comment: Unless ID is a dictionary or a simple range, the value of `p` will not provide a meaningful index when using `ID[p]` so we have to assume that the OP meant to use `for p in range(len(ID))`.

Comment: Suppose the lists are large but OP has filtered them and holds the indexes to be written in `ID`. We don't know where any of this data comes from, just that OP wants the indexes in ID to be printed in order.

Comment: If ID list would have to have all of its values equal to their indices otherwise ID[p] would crash. Why go for a convoluted and unlikely interpretation when the obvious mistake explains it perfectly (remember Occam's razor)